# 3D анимация виджетов

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, 3d, qslider

Есть ли в *PyQt5* возможность делать *3D* анимацию виджетов?

Например вращение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PyQt5** практический ни в чем вас не ограничивает и имеет любые возможности.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#############################################################################
##
## Copyright (C) 2018 Riverbank Computing Limited.
## Copyright (C) 2010 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies).
## All rights reserved.
##
## This file is part of the examples of PyQt.
##
## $QT_BEGIN_LICENSE:BSD$
## You may use this file under the terms of the BSD license as follows:
##
## "Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
## modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
## met:
##   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
##     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
##   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
##     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
##     the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
##     distribution.
##   * Neither the name of Nokia Corporation and its Subsidiary(-ies) nor
##     the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote
##     products derived from this software without specific prior written
##     permission.
##
## THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
## "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
## LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
## A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
## OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
## SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
## LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
## DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
## THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
## (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
## OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE."
## $QT_END_LICENSE$
##
#############################################################################


import sys
import math

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QSize, Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QOpenGLVersionProfile, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel,
        QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QOpenGLWidget, QScrollArea,
        QSizePolicy, QSlider, QWidget)


class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
    xRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    yRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    zRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GLWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.gear1 = 0
        self.gear2 = 0
        self.gear3 = 0
        self.xRot = 0
        self.yRot = 0
        self.zRot = 0
        self.gear1Rot = 0

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.advanceGears)
        timer.start(20)

    def setXRotation(self, angle):
        self.normalizeAngle(angle)

        if angle != self.xRot:
            self.xRot = angle
            self.xRotationChanged.emit(angle)
            self.update()

    def setYRotation(self, angle):
        self.normalizeAngle(angle)

        if angle != self.yRot:
            self.yRot = angle
            self.yRotationChanged.emit(angle)
            self.update()

    def setZRotation(self, angle):
        self.normalizeAngle(angle)

        if angle != self.zRot:
            self.zRot = angle
            self.zRotationChanged.emit(angle)
            self.update()

    def initializeGL(self):
        version_profile = QOpenGLVersionProfile()
        version_profile.setVersion(2, 0)
        self.gl = self.context().versionFunctions(version_profile)
        self.gl.initializeOpenGLFunctions()

        lightPos = (5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 1.0)
        reflectance1 = (0.8, 0.1, 0.0, 1.0)
        reflectance2 = (0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 1.0)
        reflectance3 = (0.2, 0.2, 1.0, 1.0)

        self.gl.glLightfv(self.gl.GL_LIGHT0, self.gl.GL_POSITION, lightPos)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_LIGHTING)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_LIGHT0)
        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        self.gear1 = self.makeGear(reflectance1, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.7, 20)
        self.gear2 = self.makeGear(reflectance2, 0.5, 2.0, 2.0, 0.7, 10)
        self.gear3 = self.makeGear(reflectance3, 1.3, 2.0, 0.5, 0.7, 10)

        self.gl.glEnable(self.gl.GL_NORMALIZE)
        self.gl.glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

    def paintGL(self):
        self.gl.glClear(self.gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | self.gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        self.gl.glPushMatrix()
        self.gl.glRotated(self.xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        self.gl.glRotated(self.yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        self.gl.glRotated(self.zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

        self.drawGear(self.gear1, -3.0, -2.0, 0.0, self.gear1Rot / 16.0)
        self.drawGear(self.gear2, +3.1, -2.0, 0.0,
                -2.0 * (self.gear1Rot / 16.0) - 9.0)

        self.gl.glRotated(+90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        self.drawGear(self.gear3, -3.1, -1.8, -2.2,
                +2.0 * (self.gear1Rot / 16.0) - 2.0)

        self.gl.glPopMatrix()

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        side = min(width, height)
        if side < 0:
            return

        self.gl.glViewport((width - side) // 2, (height - side) // 2, side, side)

        self.gl.glMatrixMode(self.gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        self.gl.glLoadIdentity()
        self.gl.glFrustum(-1.0, +1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 60.0)
        self.gl.glMatrixMode(self.gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
        self.gl.glLoadIdentity()
        self.gl.glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, -40.0)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        dx = event.x() - self.lastPos.x()
        dy = event.y() - self.lastPos.y()

        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setYRotation(self.yRot + 8 * dx)
        elif event.buttons() & Qt.RightButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setZRotation(self.zRot + 8 * dx)

        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def advanceGears(self):
        self.gear1Rot += 2 * 16
        self.update()    

    def xRotation(self):
        return self.xRot

    def yRotation(self):
        return self.yRot

    def zRotation(self):
        return self.zRot

    def makeGear(self, reflectance, innerRadius, outerRadius, thickness, toothSize, toothCount):
        list = self.gl.glGenLists(1)
        self.gl.glNewList(list, self.gl.GL_COMPILE)
        self.gl.glMaterialfv(self.gl.GL_FRONT, self.gl.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE,
                reflectance)

        r0 = innerRadius
        r1 = outerRadius - toothSize / 2.0
        r2 = outerRadius + toothSize / 2.0
        delta = (2.0 * math.pi / toothCount) / 4.0
        z = thickness / 2.0

        self.gl.glShadeModel(self.gl.GL_FLAT)

        for i in range(2):
            if i == 0:
                sign = +1.0
            else:
                sign = -1.0

            self.gl.glNormal3d(0.0, 0.0, sign)

            self.gl.glBegin(self.gl.GL_QUAD_STRIP)

            for j in range(toothCount+1):
                angle = 2.0 * math.pi * j / toothCount
                self.gl.glVertex3d(r0 * math.cos(angle), r0 * math.sin(angle), sign * z)
                self.gl.glVertex3d(r1 * math.cos(angle), r1 * math.sin(angle), sign * z)
                self.gl.glVertex3d(r0 * math.cos(angle), r0 * math.sin(angle), sign * z)
                self.gl.glVertex3d(r1 * math.cos(angle + 3 * delta), r1 * math.sin(angle + 3 * delta), sign * z)

            self.gl.glEnd()

            self.gl.glBegin(self.gl.GL_QUADS)

            for j in range(toothCount):
                angle = 2.0 * math.pi * j / toothCount                
                self.gl.glVertex3d(r1 * math.cos(angle), r1 * math.sin(angle), sign * z)
                self.gl.glVertex3d(r2 * math.cos(angle + delta), r2 * math.sin(angle + delta), sign * z)
                self.gl.glVertex3d(r2 * math.cos(angle + 2 * delta), r2 * math.sin(angle + 2 * delta), sign * z)
                self.gl.glVertex3d(r1 * math.cos(angle + 3 * delta), r1 * math.sin(angle + 3 * delta), sign * z)

            self.gl.glEnd()

        self.gl.glBegin(self.gl.GL_QUAD_STRIP)

        for i in range(toothCount):
            for j in range(2):
                angle = 2.0 * math.pi * (i + (j / 2.0)) / toothCount
                s1 = r1
                s2 = r2

                if j == 1:
                    s1, s2 = s2, s1

                self.gl.glNormal3d(math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle), 0.0)
                self.gl.glVertex3d(s1 * math.cos(angle), s1 * math.sin(angle), +z)
                self.gl.glVertex3d(s1 * math.cos(angle), s1 * math.sin(angle), -z)

                self.gl.glNormal3d(s2 * math.sin(angle + delta) - s1 * math.sin(angle), s1 * math.cos(angle) - s2 * math.cos(angle + delta), 0.0)
                self.gl.glVertex3d(s2 * math.cos(angle + delta), s2 * math.sin(angle + delta), +z)
                self.gl.glVertex3d(s2 * math.cos(angle + delta), s2 * math.sin(angle + delta), -z)

        self.gl.glVertex3d(r1, 0.0, +z)
        self.gl.glVertex3d(r1, 0.0, -z)
        self.gl.glEnd()

        self.gl.glShadeModel(self.gl.GL_SMOOTH)

        self.gl.glBegin(self.gl.GL_QUAD_STRIP)

        for i in range(toothCount+1):
            angle = i * 2.0 * math.pi / toothCount
            self.gl.glNormal3d(-math.cos(angle), -math.sin(angle), 0.0)
            self.gl.glVertex3d(r0 * math.cos(angle), r0 * math.sin(angle), +z)
            self.gl.glVertex3d(r0 * math.cos(angle), r0 * math.sin(angle), -z)

        self.gl.glEnd()

        self.gl.glEndList()

        return list    

    def drawGear(self, gear, dx, dy, dz, angle):
        self.gl.glPushMatrix()
        self.gl.glTranslated(dx, dy, dz)
        self.gl.glRotated(angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        self.gl.glCallList(gear)
        self.gl.glPopMatrix()

    def normalizeAngle(self, angle):
        while (angle < 0):
            angle += 360 * 16

        while (angle > 360 * 16):
            angle -= 360 * 16


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):        
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.glWidget = GLWidget()
        self.pixmapLabel = QLabel()

        self.glWidgetArea = QScrollArea()
        self.glWidgetArea.setWidget(self.glWidget)
        self.glWidgetArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.glWidgetArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.glWidgetArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.glWidgetArea.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored,
                QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.glWidgetArea.setMinimumSize(50, 50)

        self.pixmapLabelArea = QScrollArea()
        self.pixmapLabelArea.setWidget(self.pixmapLabel)
        self.pixmapLabelArea.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored,
                QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.pixmapLabelArea.setMinimumSize(50, 50)

        xSlider = self.createSlider(self.glWidget.xRotationChanged,
                self.glWidget.setXRotation)
        ySlider = self.createSlider(self.glWidget.yRotationChanged,
                self.glWidget.setYRotation)
        zSlider = self.createSlider(self.glWidget.zRotationChanged,
                self.glWidget.setZRotation)

        self.createActions()
        self.createMenus()

        centralLayout = QGridLayout()
        centralLayout.addWidget(self.glWidgetArea, 0, 0)
        centralLayout.addWidget(self.pixmapLabelArea, 0, 1)
        centralLayout.addWidget(xSlider, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        centralLayout.addWidget(ySlider, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        centralLayout.addWidget(zSlider, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        centralWidget.setLayout(centralLayout)

        xSlider.setValue(15 * 16)
        ySlider.setValue(345 * 16)
        zSlider.setValue(0 * 16)

        self.setWindowTitle("Grabber")
        self.resize(400, 300)

    def grabFrameBuffer(self):
        image = self.glWidget.grabFramebuffer()
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def clearPixmap(self):
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap())

    def about(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "About Grabber",
                "The <b>Grabber</b> example demonstrates two approaches for "
                "rendering OpenGL into a Qt pixmap.")

    def createActions(self):
        self.grabFrameBufferAct = QAction("&Grab Frame Buffer", self,
                shortcut="Ctrl+G", triggered=self.grabFrameBuffer)

        self.clearPixmapAct = QAction("&Clear Pixmap", self,
                shortcut="Ctrl+L", triggered=self.clearPixmap)

        self.exitAct = QAction("E&xit", self, shortcut="Ctrl+Q",
                triggered=self.close)

        self.aboutAct = QAction("&About", self, triggered=self.about)

        self.aboutQtAct = QAction("About &Qt", self,
                triggered=QApplication.instance().aboutQt)

    def createMenus(self):
        self.fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.grabFrameBufferAct)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.clearPixmapAct)
        self.fileMenu.addSeparator()
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAct)

        self.helpMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Help")
        self.helpMenu.addAction(self.aboutAct)
        self.helpMenu.addAction(self.aboutQtAct)

    def createSlider(self, changedSignal, setterSlot):
        slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        slider.setRange(0, 360 * 16)
        slider.setSingleStep(16)
        slider.setPageStep(15 * 16)
        slider.setTickInterval(15 * 16)
        slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksRight)

        slider.valueChanged.connect(setterSlot)
        changedSignal.connect(slider.setValue)

        return slider

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        self.pixmapLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
        size = pixmap.size()

        if size - QSize(1, 0) == self.pixmapLabelArea.maximumViewportSize():
            size -= QSize(1, 0)

        self.pixmapLabel.resize(size)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не много не то конечно, а например так же крутить QPushbotton или QLabel есть возможность?

Comment: @sergeiPython задайте другой вопрос и уточните что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается. Приложите пример вашего кода.